# Django unique together

Tags: python, django, django-models

there' s a db driven application, where there' s a table (view) defined in the db (psql) having 2 keys together as primary key. My belonging django model looks like:

```
class TS(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"t_s\".\"vt_s"'
        managed = False



class TSI(models.Model):
    ts = models.ForeignKey(TS, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT,             db_column='t_s_id')
    item_number = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"t_s\".\"vt_s_i"'
        managed = False
        unique_together = (('ts', 'item_number'),)
```

.

Or at least i thought unique_together should work like this. Running the following query in the db works fine:

```
insert into t_s.vt_s_i (t_s_id, item_number, ...) values (10, 20, ...);
```

and fails only if the (ts, item_number) combo exists already.

---

Trying to insert a TSI from the django shell however fails:

```
In [29]: ts = TS.objects.filter()[8]

In [28]: ts.id
Out[28]: 11

In [30]: ts.tsi_set.all()
Out[30]: <QuerySet []>

In [31]: tsi = TSI(description='First description', t_s = ts, item_number = '600033')

In [32]: tsi.full_clean()

In [33]: tsi.save()

In [34]: ts.tsi_set.all().values('t_s_id', 'item_number', 'description')
Out[34]: <QuerySet [{'item_number': 600033, 'description': 'First description', 't_s_id': 11}]>

In [35]: tsi = TSI(description='New description', t_s = ts, item_number = '999999')

In [36]: tsi.full_clean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-3a0eb883d57f> in <module>()
----> 1 tsi.full_clean()

~/.virtualenvs/srd/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in full_clean(self, exclude, validate_unique)
   1164 
   1165         if errors:
-> 1166             raise ValidationError(errors)
   1167 
   1168     def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):

ValidationError: {'t_s': ['T S I with this T S already exists.']}

In [37]: tsi.save()

In [38]: ts.tsi_set.all().values('task_sheet_id', 'item_number', 'description')
Out[38]: <QuerySet [{'item_number': 999999, 'description': 'New description', 't_s_id': 11}]>

In [39]:
```

. So, if there' s an empty TS (having 0 TSI) i can insert the first one with no problem. After that changing the item_number with a new insert will result a .full_clean() error, and save will overwrite instead of adding it.

Can anyone give me a solution how i should define my model to be able to insert a second tsi to any ts with different item_number? I guess unique_together in the META definition does not really work.

Thanks for the reposonds.

Comment: No this is the idea of `unique_together`, that the *combination* should be unique. So no two *rows* exist with the given values. To me it is however unclear *what* you want, what behavior do you want to implement here?

Comment: In essence `unique_together` is however a condition of a primary key, since a primary key needs to be unque as well. So I'm not really sure what behavior you do want exactly?

Comment: What backend are you using by the way? Some databases like SQLite only enforce a subset of the constraints.

Comment: The backend is postgresql, and what i' d like to achieve is to be able to add two different TSI item belonging to the same TS, but with different item_number. For some reason .full_clean() results error in this case, and i don' t quite understand what i do incorrectly... .